# Run async actions in sequence

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I have a sequence of I/O operations (DB, I/O devices...) I need to run in sequence.

```
@SafeVarargs
public final CompletableFuture<Boolean> execute(final Supplier<Boolean>... methods)
{
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = null;

    for (Supplier<Boolean> method : methods)
    {
        if (future == null)
        {
            future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(method, threadPool);
        }
        else
        {
            future.thenCombineAsync(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(method, threadPool), (result, currentResult) -> result && currentResult,
                    threadPool);
        }
    }

    return future.exceptionally(this::onException);
}
```

My code executes randomly.

1. What can I do to ensure order?
2. How can I combine results in the end? If all were true, for instance?
3. To apply a callback after everything is complete to check the result?

Comment: Which version o Java are you using? You basically want to use sync methods but you only have async methods available, am I right? Be really aware of what this can do to performance. Check the CompletableFuture docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Feel free to use .get() method to wait on the result of a Future and .allOf() method to create a Future that waits on all other futures to be completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution calls `supplyAsync()` immediately and later tries to combine the results.

If you want to guarantee sequential execution, you should use `thenApply()` or `thenCompose()` instead of `thenCombine()`:

```
for (Supplier<Boolean> method : methods)
{
    if (future == null)
    {
        future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(method, threadPool);
    }
    else
    {
        future = future.thenApplyAsync(result -> result && method.get(), threadPool);
    }
}
```

Note that this will not call the `method.get()` on the next suppliers if any of them returns false, since `&&` is short-circuiting. You could use a single `&` to force the call anyway, or swap the parameters.

This already combines all the boolean results at the end. You can add anything on the resulting `future` after the loop, like more `thenApply()` calls, or a blocking `join()` call to retrieve the `Boolean`.

Note that this loop can also easily be rewritten using streams:

```
future = Arrays.stream(methods)
        .reduce(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true),
                (f, method) -> f.thenApplyAsync(result -> result && method.get()),
                (f1, f2) -> f1.thenCombine(f2, (result1, result2) -> result1 && result2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do so by using the Spotify CompletableFutures library: https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures

They provide some really useful tools for this, for example an `allAsList` that returns a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>`.